# How to pass the values of user defined datatype variable to MS SQL from java using spring jdbc store procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have the below MS SQL store procedure with the user defined variable (`@Location`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Organization].[Organization_Insert]   
(  
 @OrganizationID NVARCHAR(256),  
 @Location Locationtype ReadOnly
)
```

`@Location` has following attributes: OrganizationSubID, LocationCode

Am using the below java class to invoke the store procedure,

```
class OrganizationInsertProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

  private final String[] outputParameters = new String[] {OUTPUT};

  public PlanActivityInsertProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, "Organization_Insert");

    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("@OrganizationID", Types.NVARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("@Location", Types.ARRAY, "Locationtype"));

    compile();
  }
```

Here, my question is, how to construct the `@Location` variable from java and pass it to the MS SQL database. (am using sqljdbc4.jar driver to connect the database)

I whole day Googled and tried many implementations and nothing paid off.

Please someone shed some lights on this...

Comment: Exactly how is the type `Locationtype` defined?  Please edit your question to include the `CREATE TYPE` statement that created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am going to assume that you have declared `Locationtype` as a table variable.  The use of `ReadOnly` on the stored procedure's parameter hints at this.)

[According to this post on the SQL Server forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/8441316a-a85f-4570-b87e-c19fb4004938/jdbc-pass-table-variable-like-you-can-with-net-c), the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't currently support table variables.  So, it seems you have to build up a string of T-SQL which declares a table variable, inserts data into the table and then executes the stored procedure.

In 'plain' JDBC, i.e. without using Spring, the code to do this looks something like the following:

```
    int numRows = /* number of rows in table variable */;

    StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder("DECLARE @Location AS LocationType;");
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        sqlBuilder.append(
            "INSERT INTO @Location (OrganizationSubID, LocationCode) VALUES (?, ?);");
    }

    sqlBuilder.append("EXEC [Organization].[Organization_Insert] ?, @Location;");

    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlBuilder.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        stmt.setString(i * 2 + 1, /* OrganizationSubID for row i */);
        stmt.setString(i * 2 + 2, /* LocationCode for row i  */);
    }

    stmt.setString(numRows * 2 + 1, /* Organization ID */);

    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    resultSet.close();
```

(I found it more helpful to call `executeQuery()` on the PreparedStatement than `execute()`.  I didn't have your sproc code, so I made `Organization_Insert` raise an error whose message contained the number of rows in the table variable.  Using `executeQuery()` was necessary to get this error message thrown in a SQLException: with `execute()` no exception was thrown.)